# Heroku and amazon RDS setup failing

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to setup a new Heroku app with amazon RDS. I've tried following the documentation here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon_rds

Which, unfortunately, isn't working for me at all. I am not using the default security group, I am using a security group called "prod_group". So, I try running the command: `rds-authorize-db-security-group-ingress --db-security-group-name prod_group \` and it tells me that the group doesn't exist. Well, I know it does. I'm using it for my main database. (Which I can connect to and communicate just fine with on my localhost setup)

If I do that command with the default, it tells me that it's missing parameters. Which, if the guide is missing parameters, how am I to know?

Not sure where to proceed from here. In fact, if there was a way to manually do it on the AWS control panel, I'd be fine with that. But I can't seem to find any manual configuration for Heroku at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: The Heroku guide references a Heroku security group, not yours. `098166147350` is the Heroku account id.

Comment: That would make sense. The second and third lines of the command were a different color, so I somehow assumed that would be the output. Thanks for this tip. I was able to get it configured, I just need to take care of some other things now. Thank you

Comment: Cool, I've added an answer below.

Comment: Thanks, hated to leave this hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heroku guide references a Heroku security group, not yours. [DEPRECATED] is the Heroku AWS account id.

Comment: This guy always causing trouble. ;) This has been deprecated since 2013.

Comment: See this post for Best Practices on using RDS database with Heroku App https://vel-lesikov.medium.com/migrating-from-heroku-postgres-to-amazon-rds-2e738e7730e5